# How can you customize the permissions dialog for CloudKit in info.plist?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, info.plist

I am currently working on an app that is going to use the users iCloud information, namely first name, last name and e-mail address as a way to automatically sign-up for the app, instead of filling out a huge form.

Currently the only way I see to get to this information, is to ask the user for permission using the only CloudKit permission type available (userDiscoverability).

```
CKContainer.default().requestApplicationPermission(CKApplicationPermissions.userDiscoverability, completionHandler: { (status, error) in

....

})
```

The problem with this is, is that the definition of userDiscoverability is:

> The current user is discoverable (through the user's email address) to
>   other users of the app

Which leads to the default dialog shown here:

[image]

The problem is, is that I want access so that i can use the information above to sign someone in automatically (and use it for when someone changes devices, loses their device, etc) so that they don't have to sign up again. Therefore the dialog shown here isn't relevant to what I  need it for and the users of the app are going to be confused as to why other users of the app will see that they are using the app(and in fact there is no functionality in the app to allow this at all anyhow).

Like other privacy entries available in Xcode, is there one available somewhere for CloudKit where I can add my own custom message so that I can customize the reason I need permission?

I know that others people have offered solutions, like providing your own custom dialog before the system asks or providing a Page View Controller to explain what's going on but I would like to avoid that. Apple really needs another permission type here but for the time being, thats all we have.

Suggestions/Comments/Feedback welcome.

Comment: I would re-think your approach.  What if people don't have CloudKit?  What if people don't want to share their iCloud account with you?  What if they want to use a different email address?  If you are using CloudKit for the storage then all of their data is automatically available on multiple/new devices.  If you aren't using it then don't abuse it.

Comment: This question was for iOS users only, so yeah CloudKit will be available. There will be an option to deny of course but then they will have to manually enter information possibly every visit. The reason i want the e-mail address is because its already been verified by apple and via CloudKit you get a unique Cloud key that represents that unique user for that specific app and its already encrypted. This keeps me from having to ask people for a username/password, make sure the password is legit and not 'password' and now people don't have to remember it either.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to ultimately sign people up in the app without filling out first name, last name, password, email, etc etc. More and more people in apps hate signing up using forms. I'm trying through this approach, to make things just happen as seamless as possible. My approach will be a PageViewController explaining why I need their basic iCloud information and hopefully they will approve.